# Property assignment to JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

```
var obj1 = {};
var obj2 = {};
var copyObj1 = obj1; 
var copyObj2 = obj2;

copyObj1 = {
    name :'abc'
};

copyObj2.name = 'xyz';

console.log("obj1",obj1); // obj1 {}
console.log("obj2",obj2); // obj2 { name: 'xyz' }
console.log("copyObj1",copyObj1); // copyObj1 { name: 'abc' }
console.log("copyObj2",copyObj2); // copyObj2 { name: 'xyz' }
```

1. Why is `obj1` value not the same as `copyObj1`, although `copyObj1` is a  reference of `obj1`?
2. What is the difference if we assign value by `{name:'abc'}` and `obj1.name ='abc'`?

Comment: `copyObj1 = {...}` is a reassignment that is, `copyObj1` holds a reference to another object afterwards. `copyObj2.name = 'xyz'` is a mutation that is, `copyObj2` holds the same object, but changes its properties. Look into [pass by value/by sharing evaluation strategies](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38533677/6445533) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

1) Why is obj1 value not the same as copyObj1, although copyObj1 is a reference of obj1?

Answer: -

You are storing the reference of obj1 to copyObj1.But this statement

```
copyObj1 = {
   name: 'abc'
};
```

creates a new object of copy1 and the reference to obj1 is now lost.

2) What is the difference if we assign value by {name:'abc'} and obj1.name ='abc'?

Answer:-

The difference between the two is when you do

```
a = {name: 'abc'} or a = {};
```

you are creating a new object and any previous reference of the object is now lost and doing

```
a.name = 'abc';
```

just changes the property value of the object.

Answer (score 1):

```
copyObj1 = {
  name :'abc'
};
```

sets `copyObj1` to a whole different object, so it now no longer points to the object pointed to by `obj1`

When you did

```
   copyObj2.name = 'xyz';
```

You assigned a new property `name` to `copyObj`

Answer (score 0):

```
   copyObj1 = {
       name :'abc'
   };
```

creates a new object, with an address that differs from obj1

```
 copyObj2.name = 'xyz'
```

doesn't, it just changes the existing copyObj2 which is in fact the same object as obj2, just by a different referencing name.

Answer (score 0):

obj1 is not a reference to copyObj1 because you reassigned copyObj1 to a new Object with

`copyObj1 = {
name : 'abc'
};`

So they point to different Objects.

With `{name: "xyz"}` you create a new Object with the property "name" while `obj1.name` adds a new property to an existing Object.